# How to get scriptable build definitions using Team Foundation Server object model?

Tags: c#, tfs, build, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

Is it possible to get Team Foundation Server 2015 new build definitions using regular object model, or am I forced to get them using the REST API?

If it's possible to using the object model, what class should I use to do so?

I was able to get XAML build definitions using `IBuildServer.QueryBuildDefinitions`. Is there an equivalent to this method so I can access new build definitions and their variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the Build 2.0 REST API's. The [documentation can be found here](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/build/overview).

There is a client wrapper which ships as part of the new NuGet packages, the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.WebApi` assembly provides a `BuildHttpClient` object which is the starting point to accessing the new build system.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at the `BuildHttpClient`.

Comment: Well, I got the whole package `<package id="Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client" version="14.83.2" targetFramework="net452" />`. Is there any documentation about how to work with these wrappers? :D

Comment: I suspect you'll need the ExtendedClient as well: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/

Comment: Yeah, be aware that this new architecture is still moving and that stuff you make may need updates in the future

Answer (score 0):

You can get the build definition using the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.BuildHttpClient`:

```
        var cred = new VssCredentials(new WindowsCredential(new NetworkCredential("{userid}", "{password}")));
        string collectionURL = "http://{tfs-server-url}:8080/tfs/{collection-name}";
        var buildClient = new BuildHttpClient(new Uri(collectionURL, UriKind.Absolute), cred);

        //this is the source project's build definition
        //http://{tfs-server-url}:8080/tfs/{collection-name}/{project-name}/_build?_a=completed&definitionId={buildDefId}
        var buildDefId = 20;
        //"http://{tfs-server-url}:8080/tfs/{collection-name}/{project-name}";
        var projectName = "{project-name}";
        var buildDef = (await buildClient.GetDefinitionAsync(projectName, buildDefId)) as BuildDefinition;

        Console.WriteLine(buildDef.Name);//here you can get all the other properties
```

`VssCredentials` class is from `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common` assembly. Replace all `{...}` with your parameters.